# Problem converting time total hours SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, powerbi-paginated-reports

```
=Floor(Fields!TotalTime.Value / 3600) &":"& Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!TotalTime.Value, "00:00"), "mm:ss")
```

I'm trying to get total sum hours in Report builder
however when the time is over 24hours it will show 1:00:00
I have tested this working formula  but I am interesting to get the same that display 25:00 instead
of 25:00:00 do you know how to do it ?

Comment: What datatype is `TotalTime`, is it datetime or just an integer with a number of seconds in it? Some sample data and expected output would be useful.

Comment: just an integer in seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
=Floor(Sum(Fields!taskTSNorm.Value, "DwReporting") / 3600) &":"& Format(DateAdd("s",Sum(Fields!taskTSNorm.Value, "DwReporting"), "00:00"), "mm")
```